# How to calculate angle for shooting bullet in 3D?

Tags: mathematics, first-person-shooter

What I want to know is if I can calculate an angle similar to how I'm doing in 2D and update the x,y,z position of a bullet based on that angle in a similar manner I'm doing the update function below.

I wrote this function in Ruby to find the target angle between two 2D (x,y) vectors, but now I want to find out how to do this in 3D in a similar way:

```
  def target_angle(point1, point2)
    x1 = point1[0]
    y1 = point1[1]
    x2 = point2[0]
    y2 = point2[1]
    delta_x = x2 - x1
    delta_y = y2 - y1
    return Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x)
  end
```

Given an object (like a bullet in this case), I can shoot the object given a target_angle between the player (x,y) and the mouse (x,y), as such in the bullet update function:

```
  def update
    wall_collision
    # the angle here is the target angle where point 1 is the player and
    # point 2 is the mouse
    @x += Math.cos(angle)*speed
    @y += Math.sin(angle)*speed
  end
```

Is there a similar method to calculate a target angle in 3D and use that angle in a similar manner as my update function (to shoot a bullet in 3D)? How can I make this work for two 3D vectors (x, y, z), where you have the player position (x,y,z) and some other arbitrary 3d point away from the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of finding the angle using `atan2` and then reconstructing the vector using `sin` and `cos` you can store the direction using a normalised vector.

This works in both 2D and 3D.

```
  def target_angle(point1, point2)
    x1 = point1[0]
    y1 = point1[1]
    x2 = point2[0]
    y2 = point2[1]
    @delta_x = x2 - x1
    @delta_y = y2 - y1

    len = Math.sqrt(@delta_x*@delta_x+@delta_y*@delta_y);
    @delta_x = @delta_x / len;
    @delta_y = @delta_y / len;
  end

  def update
    wall_collision
    # the angle here is the target angle where point 1 is the player and
    # point 2 is the mouse
    @x += @delta_x*speed
    @y += @delta_y*speed
  end
```

To do it in 3D just add the math for `z` the same way `x` and `y` are calculated.

```
len = Math.sqrt(@delta_x*@delta_x + @delta_y*@delta_y + @delta_z*@delta_z);
```

You can even ditch `speed` and store it right inside `delta_x`, `delta_y`, and `delta_z` by multiplying them by `speed` after the division by `len` to normalise them into a unit vector.

```
    @delta_x = @delta_x / len * speed;
    @delta_y = @delta_y / len * speed;
```

...

```
    @x += @delta_x
    @y += @delta_y
```

So the whole thing in 3D becomes:

```
  def target_angle(point1, point2)
    x1 = point1[0]
    y1 = point1[1]
    z1 = point1[2]
    x2 = point2[0]
    y2 = point2[1]
    z2 = point2[2]
    @delta_x = x2 - x1
    @delta_y = y2 - y1
    @delta_z = z2 - z1

    len = Math.sqrt(@delta_x*@delta_x + @delta_y*@delta_y + @delta_z*@delta_z);
    @delta_x = @delta_x / len * speed;
    @delta_y = @delta_y / len * speed;
    @delta_z = @delta_z / len * speed;
  end

  def update
    wall_collision
    # the angle here is the target angle where point 1 is the player and
    # point 2 is the mouse
    @x += @delta_x
    @y += @delta_y
    @z += @delta_z
  end
```

This way 2D is just 3D where z is always zero (so it is removed). The code is otherwise identical in working principle.

Comment: Note: `speed` could be multiplied once by baking it into `len` by doing `len /= speed` before the 3 `delta_xyz` divisions but I wanted to keep the example simple and not refactor too much of the code. Using a reciprocal for len and 3 multiplications instead would also be faster, but again: KISS for the sake of example.

Comment: I used this and it works!